# How to close tkinter window without a button and not closing Python completely?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, exit

I am aware that there are commands such as `.destroy()` , `.exit()` etc. However, when taking these out of the 'command' from the button parameter of what action to take when pressed, they don't work.

My scenario is when a user logins successfully, the Tkinter window including its widgets should close whilst short after a GUI in pygame opens. I just don't want the Tkinter window to be there once I don't need it ever again whilst also not exiting Python. I don't want a button as I want the process to be automatic.

The thing that baffles me is why when taking out this command to be on its own, it does not work:

```
Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).pack() #works
root.destroy() #don't works
```

Comment: After successful login in the same function call root.destroy()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of the source code, I guess the problem is based on *where* you call `root.destroy()`

If it comes after the blocking `tk.mainloop()`, it will never be reached. Please read [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947) regarding this issue.

A possible solution based on the above:

```
while True:
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    if login_successful: # or whatever your login check looks like
        root.destroy()
```

You replace the `mainloop` with your custom loop, which includes a check for a successful login.

Comment: Exactly what I was missing. I left the mainloop() which like you said didn't allow me to reach to .destroy() . Thank you smart sir! (quick response too I must say)